# Growing decision tree with igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph, decision-tree

[image]

I have this graph using `igraph`, but i'm looking to grow the tree as if it were a decision tree. I can't draw it, but is it possible to grow a second node `Tr` under `Hun` instead of an edge going from `Hun` to `Tr` that is also connected to `Pat`?

I am using `graph_from_data_frame` with a dataframe of links and nodes.

```
nodes <- cbind('id' = c( 'Pat', 'Fa', 'Tr', 'Hun', 
               'Type'),
               'type' = NA)

# Define links 
links <- cbind('from' = c( rep('Pat', 3), 
                           rep('Hun', 2 )), 
               'to' = c('Hun', 'Fa', 'Tr', 
                        'Type', 'Tr'))

# create tree
net <- graph_from_data_frame(links, vertices = nodes, directed = T)
plot(net, 
     layout = layout.reingold.tilford(net, root=1), 
     vertex.size = 24)
```

Comment: You want two nodes named Tr?

Comment: Yes, and they are separated. one is from `pat`, the other is from `Hun`.

Comment: I doubt  that is possible. Do you want to create  a decision tree, (maybe with predefined rules) and use igraph only for plotting purpose? That might be possible with some decision tree handling package like rpart, but I am not sure about that either. You can take a look at rpart and rattle packages and check.